# Metrizable space is compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $(X,\tau)$ a metrizable space, such that every metric that generates $\tau$ is bounded. Prove that $X$ is compact.

**My attempt**. Let $d$ a metric such that $\tau_d= \tau$ then by hypothesis $d$ is bounded, so $X$ is bouded. I have thought to prove that X is sequentially compact, but I don't know if that is true.

Comment: There are lots of bounded metrics on non-compact metric spaces (e.g., $\Bbb R^n$).

Comment: A metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded, try to work with this.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If $(X,d)$ is not (sequentially) compact, then there is a sequence of disjoint balls $B(x_n,r_n)$ with $r_n>0$.  Define an (unbounded) function $f\colon x\in X\mapsto\sum_n n\cdot\max(0,r_n-d(x,x_n))\in\mathbb{R}$ and a new metric $\tilde{d}$ on $X$ by
$$
\tilde{d}(x,x'):=d(x,x')+\lvert f(x)-f(x')\rvert.
$$